# mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass reference not found

Tags: c#, powershell

My friend and I we both have the mshtml.dll class
With documents function

but there problem I have a lot more functions and class than my friends have.

One of my main class he needs is `mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass`
but he has `mshtml.HTMLDocument`

I have it in my dll and I wonder why that happend.

I installed to him silverlight (i found on technet that some class is in that). Still no change.

Looking for help.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Add Microsoft.mshtml reference to the project , then by namespace "mshtml" you will have access to HTMLDocumentClass

Comment: nope, he can use it but not have the Class one

he have mshtml.HTMLDocument
but not  mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass